# Objective C: iOS: Audio Streaming and Audio Uploading using RTMP

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, streaming, rtmp

I have to record the high volume sound. It can be upto 60 seconds. The application is already made on flash and the current flash application uses rtmp (red5 server) and streams the recording to the server in real time as **FLV**. I have uploaded the audio file on server as mp3 from iOS application but this approach is not useful as the volume is very high as mentioned above. So I want to use **rtmp (red5 server)** for iOS application. I want to ask is it possible that I can record the audio and upload on this server and also can steam from there?

**Edit-1:** I want to ask that whether Apple can reject the application if we use the RTMP iOS library in our application?

**Edit-2:** I did some research and found some 3rd party libraries like:
http://www.aftek.com/afteklab/aftek-iphone-RTMP-library.shtml
I want to know, whether it is possible to directly connect from iOS to RTMP server?
Or these libraries use the middle layer approach with HTTP to connect to RTMP?
Example: iOS -> HTTP Server -> RTMP Server (red5)

I will appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you done any research into solving the problem? Do you have a part solution?

Comment: I did some research on this. But I did not get some useful information. If you can direct me on the right path with some useful links or information, I would appreciate.